# Python calling raw_input from a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm calling a python script from the below one using subprocess. From the command line the user chooses which file to open using raw_input

```
import optparse
import subprocess
import readline
import os

def main():

    options = {'0': './option_0.py',
            '1': './option_1.py',
            '2': './option_2.py',
            '3': './option_3.py'}
    input = -1

    while True:
        if input in options:
            file = options[input]
            subprocess.Popen(file)
        else:
            print "Welcome"
            print "0. option_0"
            print "1. option_1"
            print "2. option_2"
            print "3. option_3"
            input = raw_input("Please make a selection: ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However on the subprocess called(say option_1.py is called) I have a problem using raw_input again to accept prompt from the user. I am aware of the .PIPE arguments and have tried

```
subprocess.Popen(file, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But again no luck.

Comment: I personally would make this as non-interactive as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example where the subprocess receives my input:

```
import subprocess
import sys

command = 'python -c \'print raw_input("Please make a selection: ")\''
sp = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdin = sys.stdin)
sp.wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to redirect the current standard input to the subprocess. Which can be done this way:

```
subprocess.Popen(file, stdin=sys.stdin, ...)
```