# Interacting with multiple Python scripts through one command line window

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I've got two scripts, both run from the windows command line (they contain argparse objects).

These interact in the following way:
The first script determines which parser arguments to hand to the second script, it then formats them correctly and hands them to the second script through some form of subprocessess.call() arrangement.

When the second script requires no user interaction through the command line this all works fine.  When the user is prompted for inputs by the seconds script as part of its processing, however, it all locks up.

How can I interact with the second script through the same command line that I'm running the first script in?

The second script can be one of several different ones, so any method would have to be flexible enough to handle passing any arguments to any script

Cheers

Comment: Don't use subprocess.call, but just import the second script, and run the necessary functions

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated the question slightly.  The second script isn't always the same.  Surely I'd have to hard-code the importing of the scripting functions that I wanted to use?  The great benefit of the subprocess is that by passing a cmd line argument I can use any script and any arguments

Comment: In that case, use the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081124/python-calling-raw-input-from-a-subprocess), basically, add an `stdin = sys.stdin` argument to subprocess

Comment: Amazing, thanks!  How does that work?  Would
    stdout=sys.stdout
also help?

Comment: You can dynamically import scripts in Python, ya know

Comment: @Mathias711: Shouldn't the default, `stdin=None`, behave exactly the same as `stdin=sys.stdin`?

Comment: @remram apparently not, but it's strange (I think) this isn't the default option. I'm not sure though, I just googled for my answer